# NewAg-ApiKey format errors

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-powershell

I'm trying to run the `NewAg-ApiKey` cmdlet in aws powershell. I'm unsure on the format of the `StageKeys` . Can someone clarify this?

Currently writing the `New-AgApiKey` as:

```
New-AGApiKey -CustomerId '11' -Description 'aa' -Enabled $True -GenerateDistinctId $True -Name 'newAPIKey'-StageKeys [{"RestApiId":'yz50sp19a7'},{"StageName":'wh1'}] -Force
```

and getting the following errors

> At C:\Users\sgoswami\Desktop\Scripts\create1.ps1:2 char:132
>   + ...  $True -Name 'newAPIKey'-StageKeys [{"RestApiId":'yz50sp19a7'},{"Stag ...
>   +                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token ':'yz50sp19a7'' in expression or statement. At
>   C:\Users\sgoswami\Desktop\Scripts\create1.ps1:2 char:159
>   + ... Key'-StageKeys [{"RestApiId":'yz50sp19a7'},{"StageName":'wh1'}] -Forc ...
>   +                                                            ~~~~~~ Unexpected token ':'wh1'' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the ApiKey without StageKeys at all. It isn't a required parameter, and per the [New-AGApiKey documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-AGApiKey.html) this parameter has been deprecated in favor of [usage plans](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-usage-plans-for-amazon-api-gateway/):

> -StageKey StageKey[]
>
> DEPRECATED FOR USAGE PLANS - Specifies stages associated with the API key.
>   Required? False
>   Position? Named
>   Accept pipeline input?    False

This option has likewise been deprecated in the CLI and other SDKs.

If you still need to use StageKeys, the [Amazon.APIGateway.Model.StageKey type is defined here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=EC2/TEC2Filter.html&tocid=Amazon_EC2_Model_Filter), in the AWS SDK for .NET documentation. You can create a new instance of this type in powershell as described below, where a powershell with matching property names and values is used as input for the new object:

```
$obj = New-Object Amazon.APIGateway.Model.StageKey -Property @{ RestApiId = "myId"; StageName = "myName" }
```

To verify the type is correct:

```
$obj | get-member

   TypeName: Amazon.APIGateway.Model.StageKey

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
RestApiId   Property   string RestApiId {get;set;}
StageName   Property   string StageName {get;set;}
```

Comment: This works. . However,I am getting a new error for the syntax. any specific reason this could be happening.
New-AGApiKey -CustomerId '11' -Description 'aa' -Enabled $True -Gener ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AGApiKey], TypeInitializationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.AG.NewAGApiKeyCmdlet

for 
  New-AGApiKey -CustomerId '11' -Description 'aa' -Enabled $True -GenerateDistinctId $True -Name 'newAPIKey'-StageKeys $obj -Force

Comment: Hello, why exactly are you trying to use deprecated functionality?